# How to set Excel cell format in iReport

Tags: export-to-excel, ireport, cell-formatting

I'm trying to export a report as xls, but when i open my exported file i notice that all cell formats are Number and all data are wrote with ' like text data (integer fields and double fields also...) so i cant apply any formula like SUM in Excel.

How can i keep cell format in according to my iReport TextField class expression?

I'm using iReport 4.0.2.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i've been looking for the same problem and found the following:

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsformula/index.html

you can set up the "detect cell type" to default true under export excel settings in ireport.

regards

Answer (score 0):

In your `<textField>` element use this:

```
<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="fb1a31bf-e600-4ed0-8eb1-2e48f82b90ce">
  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern" value="0.00"/>
</reportElement>
```

where `value="..."` is your cell pattern.